# Concatenate values in Json object in postgres 9.6 function

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, loops

im trying to iterate a json in a postgres function, receive a json array, im confuse how to concat some values in the object, and then add to a json object array, my code is the next

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setProduct(val json) 
RETURNS JSON AS $$
DECLARE 
varvariedad INTEGER;
vartallo INTEGER;
varlista INTEGER;
varcaja INTEGER;
objetoinsert JSON;
objetorespuesta JSON;
objetovariedadesnot JSON;
objetopreciosnot JSON;

i JSON;
BEGIN 
objetoinsert :='[]';
objetorespuesta :='[]';
objetovariedadesnot:='[]';
objetopreciosnot :='[]';

 FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(val)
  LOOP
  /*valido variedad*/
    varvariedad:=0;
    select id into varvariedad from variedad_flors where nombre = trim( i->>'nombre');

        IF varvariedad  > 0 THEN
        vartallo:=0;
        select id into vartallo from tallos where nombre = trim( i->>'tallo');

                IF vartallo == 0 THEN
                objetovariedadesnot := objetovariedadesnot || '{"error":"No existe Tallo", "qty": "'||trim( i->>'qty')||'", "caja": "'||trim( i->>'caja')+'", "tallo": "'||trim( i->>'tallo')||'", "precio": "'|| trim( i->>'precio')||'"}'::jsonb; 
                ELSE
                varcaja:=0;
                select id into varcaja from tallos where nombre = trim( i->>'caja');

                        IF varcaja == 0 THEN
                        objetovariedadesnot := objetovariedadesnot || '{"error":"No existe Caja", "qty": "'||trim( i->>'qty')||'", "caja": "'||trim( i->>'caja')||'",, "tallo": "'||trim( i->>'tallo')||'", "precio": "'||trim( i->>'precio')||'"}}'::jsonb;    

                        ELSE
                         varlista:=0;
                         select id into varlista from listaprecio where variedad = trim(varvariedad);

                            IF varlista == 0 THEN
                                objetopreciosnot := objetopreciosnot || '{"error":"No existe List de precio", "qty": "'||trim( i->>'qty')||'", "caja": "'||trim( i->>'caja')||'", "tallo": "'||trim( i->>'tallo')||'", "precio": "'||trim( i->>'precio')||'"}'::jsonb;  
                            ELSE
                                objetoinsert := objetoinsert ||'{"id_listaprecios":"'||varlista||'", "cantidad": '|| i->>'qty'||', "id_variedad": "'||varvariedad||'"}';
                            END IF;
                        END IF; 
                END IF;
        ELSE
                 objetovariedadesnot := objetovariedadesnot || '{"error":"No existe variedad", "qty": "'||trim( i->>'qty')||'", "caja": "'||trim( i->>'caja')||'", "tallo": "'||trim( i->>'tallo')||'", "precio": ' || trim( i->>'precio')|| '}'::jsonb;    
        END IF;
  END LOOP;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```

the error is about to concat the "}}", how i can concat everything i the right way to avoid the next error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 1: ...tallo')||'", "precio": ' || trim( i->>'precio')|| '}}'::json...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Expected JSON value, but found "}".
QUERY:  SELECT objetovariedadesnot || '{"error":"No existe variedad", "qty": "'||trim( i->>'qty')||'", "caja": "'||trim( i->>'caja')||'", "tallo": "'||trim( i->>'tallo')||'", "precio": ' || trim( i->>'precio')|| '}}'::jsonb
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: }...
PL/pgSQL function setproduct(json) line 50 at assignment

********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Expected JSON value, but found "}".
Context: JSON data, line 1: }...
PL/pgSQL function setproduct(json) line 50 at assignment
```

Thanks a lot for your help, im searching about this in google but, i cant find something similar to my error

Comment: It would be better for you if you use the Postgres JSON functions as `json_insert()` instead of string concatenation. They ensure that the JSON structure remains valid https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Comment: Thanks, i really was complicating everything, i change the function to save in a temp table and not to push in the arrays, then, finish the iteration, read the tables  and convert to json

Answer (score 0):

i was lost beginning to learn postgres, i change the logic of the function, so if someone need to do some similar, this is the code, at final i cast some json values, save in a temp table everything, and the answer, read the temp table and cast to json, so finally we dont need to concat string with json values

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setProduct(val json) 
RETURNS JSON AS $$
DECLARE 
varvariedad INTEGER;
vartallo INTEGER;
varlista INTEGER;
varcaja INTEGER;
objetoinsert JSON;
objetorespuesta JSON;
i JSON;
BEGIN 

/*
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_respuesta
   (
      error bigint,
      message VARCHAR(150),
      variedad VARCHAR(150),
      qty bigint,
      caja VARCHAR(20),
      tallo varchar(20)
   ) 
   ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;*/

 FOR i IN SELECT * FROM json_array_elements(val)
  LOOP
  /*valido variedad*/
    varvariedad:=0;
        raise notice 'empiezo: %',i->>'variedad' ;
    select id into varvariedad from variedad_flors where nombre = trim( i->>'variedad');

        IF varvariedad  > 0 THEN
        vartallo:=0;
        select id into vartallo from tallos_flors where nombre = trim( i->>'tallo');

                IF vartallo = 0 THEN
                insert into temp_variedadesnot 
                (error,message,variedad,qty,caja,tallo) VALUES (1,'No existe Tallo',varlista,i->>'variedad',i->>'qty'::BIGINT,i->>'caja',i->>'tallo');
                ELSE
                varcaja:=0;
                select id into varcaja from cajas_flors where nombre = trim( i->>'caja');

                        IF varcaja = null THEN
                        insert into tmp_respuesta 
                        (error,message,variedad,qty,caja,tallo) VALUES (1,'No existe caja',i->>'variedad',(i->>'qty')::BIGINT,i->>'caja',i->>'tallo');
                        ELSE
                         varlista:=0;
                         select id into varlista from listaprecios where id_tipoflor = varvariedad;

                            IF varlista = 0 THEN
                                insert into tmp_respuesta (error,message,variedad,qty,caja,tallo) VALUES 
                                (2,'No existe Lista de precio',i->>'variedad',(i->>'qty')::BIGINT,i->>'caja',i->>'tallo');
                            ELSE
                                insert into productos (id_listaprecios,cantidad,id_variedad) VALUES (varlista,(i->>'qty')::BIGINT,varvariedad);
                                insert into tmp_respuesta (error,message,variedad,qty,caja,tallo) VALUES 
                                (0,'Registro Exitoso',i->>'variedad',(i->>'qty')::BIGINT,i->>'caja',i->>'tallo');
                            END IF;
                        END IF; 
                END IF;
        ELSE
             insert into tmp_respuesta 
             (error,message,variedad,qty,caja,tallo) VALUES (1,'No existe Variedad' ,varlista,(i->>'qty')::BIGINT,i->>'caja',i->>'tallo');
        END IF;
  END LOOP;


    select json_agg(row_to_json(tmp_respuesta)) into objetoinsert from tmp_respuesta;
    return objetoinsert ; 
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```